# Windows-like skype on ubuntu

Tags: skype

Is there a way to launch windows-like skype on ubuntu?
Official microsoft's client looks ugly, those 3 separate windows(i havent found how to unite them in one at least).
Tried portable version+wine - it doesnt work.
So, is there such a way?
Or, at least, how do i unite those 3 separate windows?
I'm new to linux, using it only for 3 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) or [CrossoVer](https://www.codeweavers.com/products/). 
Install Skype for Windows using them. But I do not recommend doing like this.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a little late but can be good for future visitors:
Skype has released a new alpha version of skype for Linux based on it's web UI.
You can see the community here:
https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299
and download it for Debian here:
https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading-web/?type=weblinux-deb